# when I opened ADT it shows an error that android requires toolkit 23.0.0 but current version is 22.6

Tags: android, version, adt

when I opened ADT it shows an error that android requires toolkit 23.0.0 but current version is 22.*.I uninstalled previous version from  already installed 22.* version and installed 23.* version but again it shows the same error when I close and open ADT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when I get such ADT version errors, I download a complete ADT with SDK pack from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and install it again... This is simplier and faster then finding  what causes the problem...

Answer (score 0):

just update your adt to version 23.* .if you use eclipse for development ,choose 'Check for update'  choice to update your adt